# equivalent of |more for python dir / help()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spyder

I'm using the Spyder ide and if I do `help(scipy.sparse.coo_matrix)` I get a lot of output on the screen. Is it possible to display it page by page? Something like what  `| more` does on Bash. e.g. `ls | more`

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To activate a pager inside our consoles, you need to go to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Display`

and activate the option called `Use a pager to display additional text inside the console`.

However, a way more comfortable way to read docs inside Spyder is by simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on macOS) in front of an object and see those docs rendered as an html page inside our Help pane.

*Note*: Paging is broken as of October 2020. Given that's been the case for years without no one noticing it, we decided to remove it in our next version (4.2.0), to be released in November 2020.

Comment: I activated the option, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Output is not displayed page by page. But thanks for Ctrl + I

Comment: @Nachiket, thanks for pointing that out. We'll fix that bug in our next version.